# forward slash not followed by any character

Tags: regex, python-2.7

I've the following challenge.

I need a regex to find all lines that contain an URL that ends with .net or .net/ but not followed by any other character.

my regex so far:

```
r'://[a-zA-z0-9.]+\.net(/*)'
```

But how to ignore an URL like www.xxxxxx.net/search or www.xxxxxx.net/q=

URL is not always at end of line !

Example lines:

```
"xxxxxxxxxxx, http://www.blog.net; 2 subscribers)"
"yyyyyyyyyyy, http://www.blog.net/; 2 subscribers)"
"zzzzzzzzzzz, http://www.blog.net/search; 2 subscribers)"
"rrrrrrrrrrr, http://www.blog.net/search"
"rrrrrrrrrrr, http://www.blog.net/q=;
```

Comment: What does "not followed by any other character" mean then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following might work for your sample input:

```
r'https?://[a-zA-z0-9.]+\.net/?'
```

Comment: URL is not always at end of line !

Comment: @devnull i think it will be better to replace `$` with `(?!\S|$)` to handle multiple urls in same line.

Comment: @Robertico The original answer without the anchor would work for you.  Edited above.

Comment: I got it...oeps...learned something new and I can still use the examples. Thx a million all !!!

Answer (score 1):

You can use a lookahead:

```
r'://[a-zA-z0-9.]+\.net(/?)(?!\S|$)'
```

This matches as long as the optional `/` is not followed by a non-whitespace character.